# Redirect from a Service in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a service that looks up data for a page, but if that data isn't found, should redirect to the homepage.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this in Sf2.  There are so many different ways to work with services and router, but none seem to work.

```
namespace Acme\SomeBundle\Services;

use Acme\SomeBundle\Entity\Node;
use \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use \Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class NodeFinder
{

    private $em;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, Router $router)
    {

        $this->em = $em;
        $this->router = $router;

    }

    public function getNode($slug)
    {

        $node = $this->em->getRepository('SomeBundle:Node')->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug));

        if (!$node) { //if no node found

                return  $this->router->redirect('homepage', array(), true);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Symfony2, services are not made for redirections. You should try to change your service like that :

```
namespace Acme\SomeBundle\Services;

use Acme\SomeBundle\Entity\Node;
use \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class NodeFinder
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getNode($slug)
    {
        $node = $this->em->getRepository('SomeBundle:Node')->findOneBy(array(
            'slug' => $slug
        ));
        return ($node) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

then in you controller you call your service and make the redirection :

```
// in the controller file

$nodefinder = $this->container->get('your_node_finder_service_name');

if (!$nodefinder->getNode($slug)) {
    $this->redirect('homepage');
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The problem is that I use this service in many places, so there is a lot of code duplication doing the redirect in the controller.

Comment: Sllly is right, you should be doing any redirects in your controller, not in your service.

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel because? I have many times `if user is not logged in, redirect to login page` really? I have to duplicate this 100 times? bad bad bad

Answer (score 5):

you could do this in your service ( writing out of my head)

```
class MyException extends \Exception
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public $redirectResponse;
}

class MyService 
{    
    public function doStuff() 
    {
        if ($errorSituation) {
            $me = new MyException()
            $me->redirectResponse = $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('loginpage'));
            throw $me;
         }
    }
}

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function doAction()
    {
        try {
            // call MyService here
        } catch (MyException $e) {
            return $e->redirectResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Although this is not perfect, it is certainly a lot better than what sllly was trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Inject the **router** service in your service. Than you can return a **new RedirectResponse**. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104002/redirecting-in-service-symfony2).

Answer (score 1):

From Symfony point of view you can create a controller as a service and so make redirection from this service.
The syntax is :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

return new RedirectResponse($url, $status);
```

More info can be found here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html#alternatives-to-base-controller-methods