# Redirecting in service - symfony2

Tags: symfony

May I perform redirection to another controller within service?

I have implemented a service based on example provided by [@Artamiel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091633/service-in-symfony2-how-service-file-should-look-like).

My function code which is executed by controller looks like this:

```
 public function verifyanddispatch() {
        $session = $this->request->getSession();
        if(!$session->get("App_Books_Chosen_Lp")) return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_listbooks'));
    }
```

I have checked and `!$session->get("App_Books_Chosen_Lp")` is true. Nonetheless I am not redirected to `app_listbooks` controller.

I think that this is because I return redirect response not directly in controller rather than in a service.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know how you defined your service but example below works fine. Assuming that you're calling service from your controller.

**services.yml**

```
services:
    application_backend.service.user:
        class: Application\BackendBundle\Service\UserService
        arguments:
            - @router
```

**Service class**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class UserService
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(
        RouterInterface $router
    ) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername('hello');
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('application_frontend_default_index'));
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    //.........

    return $this->userService->create();
}
```

**UPDATE**

---

Although original answer above answers original question, it is not the best practise so do the following if you want a better way. First of all do not inject `@router` into service and do the following changes.

```
// Service
public function create()
{
    .....
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername('hello');
    $this->entityManager->persist($user);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    .....
}

// Controller
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $this->userService->create();

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate(........);
    } catch (......) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException(.....);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not perform "return" in controller.

Comment: Controller A calls service. Service returns `RedirectResponse` back to controller A. Controller A returns `RedirectResponse` as a result which is what triggers the actual redirection to controller B. Example above works this way.

Comment: Someone was brave enough to downvote this answer but wasn't man enough to explain why so that we all could learn what't wrong with it!

Comment: While this works, it probably is not the cleanest solution.By returning a redirect response in the service, you are creating a tight coupling to the Symfony Http Foundation. It would be better to throw an exception as Moritz suggests, and catch that in the controller or even an exception listener.

Answer (score 9):

From an architecture point of view one should not create a `RedirectResponse` in a service. One way could be to throw an exception in the service, which is caught in the controller's action where you can easily create a `RedirectResponse`.

An example can be found here: [Redirect from a Service in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615550/redirect-from-a-service-in-symfony2)

Comment: This is definitely the way to do it clean.

Comment: Totally agree this is a clean way

Comment: Throwing an exception implies something went wrong. On reading such code I'd assume it was catching a problem scenario and sending the user elsewhere to resolve it, or this controller just can't handle it etc. Also service shouldn't handle redirect at all, just pass back some state - exception, data, or nothing

Answer (score 2):

It seems to make the redirection from service you have to pass to controller either `RedirectResponse` object or value that will tell controller that everything within service went fine and no redirection is needed (in example below: "true" value). Then you have to verify in controller which value was provided (whether it is "true" or `RedirectResponse`) and either return `RedirectResponse` again within controller or do nothing.

Example below should tell everything.

Service:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class nobookchoosenService {

    /* @var $request Request */
    private $request;

    /* @var $router RouterInterface */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, RouterInterface $router) {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function verifyanddispatch() {
        $session = $this->request->getSession();
        if(!$session->get("App_Books_Chosen_Lp"))  return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_listbooks'));
        else return true;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
$checker = $this->get('nobookchoosen_service')->verifyanddispatch();
        if($checker != "true") return  $checker;
```

Comment: This worked great but you are returning a boolean so you should check: if($checker !== true) return $checker;

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with @Moritz that redirections must be done inside controllers.

But sometimes happens that some redirection would be useful if done from a local function inside a controller.

In this case a solution could be to create a custom Exception Class (RedirectException).

Here you are a link to an interesting post: https://www.trisoft.ro/blog/56-symfony-redirecting-from-outside-the-controller.

I know it's debatable, but has sense if it's used within a local function inside its Controller.

To summarize, the steps would be:

> 1) Create a RedirectException class
>
> 2) Create a Kernel Listener
>
> 3) Set Up the Service in the configuration service file (service.yml)
>
> 4) Throw an exception with the url to redirect when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but I would not recommend it. To redirect from service you should provide proper `API` for you event for example like in: `FOSUserBundle` where you are receiving instance of `FilterUserResponseEvent` and you can set response on that event object:

```
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    // dependencies
    // ...

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS     => 'onSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onSuccess(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('some_url');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

This is possible thanks to controller:

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
    // create response
}
// return response from event
```