# How to call redirectToRoute method accept controller in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am new in symfony, I do some process after any user login in system, for that make a one service, Code Below :

```
security.authentication.success_handler:
        class:   AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
        arguments:  ["@security.http_utils", {}]
        tags:
            - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

In Security file Add one line, Code Below :

```
success_handler: security.authentication.success_handler
```

Make a new `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` file In folder handler, Code Below :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options ) {

        parent::__construct( $httpUtils,$options);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token ) {
        $user=$token->getUser();
        if (!empty($user) && $user->hasRole('ROLE_MEDICAL_PROVIDER')) {
            if($user->getMedicalProvider()->getIsRegistrationCompleted() != 1) {
                if($user->getMedicalProvider()->getRequestAssistance() == 1) {


                    return $this->redirectToRoute('registration_medical_provider_step'.$user->getMedicalProvider()->getRequestAssistanceStep());


                } else {
                    return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->determineTargetUrl($request));
                }
            } else {
                return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->determineTargetUrl($request));    
            }

        }
        else {
            return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->determineTargetUrl($request));    
        }

    }
}
```

I want to redirect to another route after login base on condition  above code i user and it give me error below:

> Error: Call to undefined method redirectToRoute() In
>   AuthenticationSuccessHandler.php file

How I call method from login authentication success handler file in symfony ?

Answer (score 3):

You're not in a controller so you could try something like:

```
return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, 'registration_medical_provider_step'.$user->getMedicalProvider()->getRequestAssistanceStep());
```

Comment: It give me below error after use above code:                                   
          Attempted to call an undefined method named "generateUrl" of class "AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler".

Comment: Updated. You could use directly httpUtils which you have already. Check `HttpUtils::createRedirectResponse()` which returns exactly what you want passing the `$request` and a `path` or `route name` as second param.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler, so **redirectToRoute()**
method does not exist in this class.

however, you can try this

`$this->httpUtils->generateUri($request, 'your_target_path');`

Read more [HttpUtils](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/HttpUtils.html) 
and see this method
`generateUri(Request $request, string $path)`

Comment: how to use route name becuz I have route name not full path .

Comment: I think then you need to inject the RouterInterface. check 
 this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104002/redirecting-in-service-symfony2